# facing issue with the c++ microsoft extension and the intellisense is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
[Error - 2:15:08 AM] Sending notification cpptools/activeDocumentChange failed.
Error: Connection is disposed.
    at throwIfClosedOrDisposed (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:50645:19)
    at Object.sendNotification (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:50692:13)
    at Object.sendNotification (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:51747:56)
    at LanguageClient.sendNotification (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:53439:38)
    at c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37838:33
    at c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37513:21
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at task (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37512:28)
    at DefaultClient.<anonymous> (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37455:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36089:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_modules__.9325.__awaiter (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36085:12)
    at nextTask (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37453:40)
    at DefaultClient.<anonymous> (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37471:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36089:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_modules__.9325.__awaiter (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36085:12)
    at DefaultClient.queueTask (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37451:16)
    at DefaultClient.notifyWhenLanguageClientReady (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37515:21)
    at DefaultClient.activeDocumentChanged (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:37837:14)
    at ClientCollection.replace (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:38447:35)
    at c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36934:67
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ClientCollection.forEach (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:38423:25)
    at Object.closed (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:36934:36)
    at LanguageClient.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:53867:55)
    at LanguageClient.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:55049:15)
    at closeHandler (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:53846:18)
    at CallbackList.invoke (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:49575:39)
    at Emitter.fire (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:49633:36)
    at closeHandler (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:50207:26)
    at CallbackList.invoke (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:49575:39)
    at Emitter.fire (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:49633:36)
    at StreamMessageReader.fireClose (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:51023:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\l\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.4.0-insiders3\dist\main.js:51063:46)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
[Error - 2:15:08 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue, the difference is I had installed the 1.6.0(insiders) of c/c++ extension.
What I do is to reinstall the previous version, like 1.5.1, and restart the VSCode, then everything works fine.

This solution works for me. I hope it can help too.

[image: The way to install the previous version]

Comment: Now 1.7.0 doesn't work and I had to revert to 1.6.0 lol